# How do I serve `sphinx` documentation locally?

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx

During development, it would be nice to build the documentation and then serve it locally so that I can inspect the latest changes. What is the best way to serve locally?

`mkdocs` has a built-in command `mkdocs serve`, but I don't see any such equivalent for `sphinx`.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing is probably to just use Python's built in http server, e.g.

```
python -m http.server
```

(run in your Sphinx output directory)

Comment: The output directory could be named `_build` in some projects

Answer (score 2):

The [sphinx-autobuild](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autobuild/) package is meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t really need that. Just find a generated web page (index page or not) and launch it in a web browser.